# Animation of snake on wpf border

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, grid, border

I have a `WPF` grid with a border.

I wanted to know if on the load of the screen I can draw the border slowly like a **snake** until it is finished.

By animation or in some way?

Comment: I don't see simple solutions, but two things come into mind: StrokeDashArray and Opacity Masks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by replacing border with individual Lines and animating these Lines size. Here is a KaXaml snippet:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid Margin="20">  
  <Line X1="0" X2="1" Y1="0" Y2="0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Fill" x:Name="topLine">
    <Line.RenderTransform>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0" />
    </Line.RenderTransform>
  </Line>
  <Line X1="0" X2="1" Y1="0" Y2="0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Stretch="Fill" x:Name="bottomLine" RenderTransformOrigin="1,0">
    <Line.RenderTransform>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0" />
    </Line.RenderTransform>
  </Line>
  <Line X1="0" X2="0" Y1="0" Y2="1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Stretch="Fill" x:Name="rightLine">
    <Line.RenderTransform>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0" />
    </Line.RenderTransform>
  </Line>
  <Line X1="0" X2="0" Y1="0" Y2="1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="Fill" x:Name="leftLine" RenderTransformOrigin="0,1">
    <Line.RenderTransform>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0" />
    </Line.RenderTransform>
  </Line>
  <Grid.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard SpeedRatio="5">
              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="topLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" To="1" />
              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rightLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" To="1" BeginTime="0:0:1" />
              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bottomLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" To="1" BeginTime="0:0:2" />
              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="leftLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" To="1" BeginTime="0:0:3" />
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
      </EventTrigger>
  </Grid.Triggers>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: You know how I can draw a line from the bottom to top? for the right side of the window?